# Swift - Grab data from Firebase and store it into an array

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, tableview

I am trying to grab a list of bars from a Firebase Database and store it in an array so I can display it in a table view.

I have configured Firebase and managed to get data in the app as String, AnyObject dictionary.

Here is my code :

```
struct Bar {

    var latitude: Double?
    var longitude: Double?
    var name: String!
    var phoneNumber: String?
    var happyHour: String?
    var url: NSURL?
    var barLogo: UIImage?
    var followers: Int?
    var addedToFavorites: Int?
    var zipCode: Double?
    var area: String?

}


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
    var refHandle: UInt!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        refHandle = ref.observe(FIRDataEventType.value , with: {(snapshot) in
            let dataDict = snapshot.value as! [String : AnyObject]



        }
        )
 }
```

Here is my JSON exported from Firebase:

```
{
  "data" : {
    "bars" : {
      "bar1" : {
        "addedToFavorites" : 0,
        "area" : "upper east",
        "follwers" : 0,
        "happyHour" : "m-f 16-19",
        "lattitude" : 4412334,
        "longitude" : 223455,
        "name" : "bar1",
        "phone" : 212222,
        "url" : "http://www.bar1.com",
        "zipCode" : 12345
      },
      "bar2" : {
        "addedToFavorites" : 0,
        "area" : "upper west",
        "follwers" : 0,
        "happyHour" : "f - s 20-22",
        "lattitude" : 4443221,
        "longitude" : 221234,
        "name" : "bar 2",
        "phone" : 215555,
        "url" : "http://www.bar2.com",
        "zipCode" : 54321
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What would be the best approach for this?

I would like to scale it and download hundreds of bars, so manually grabbing the data from the dictionary and storing it into a Bar struct variable and then appending it to an array is not a path I want to go on.

I need a solution to grab all the bars and somehow adding them to an array (or any other method to display them into a tableView).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to solve this issue :

First of all I got rid of the struct and created a class :

My class file :

```
import Foundation  
import UIKit

    class Bar {

        private var _name: String!
        private var _area: String!
        private var _latitude: Double!
        private var _longitude: Double!
        private var _followers: Int!
        private var _happyHour: String!
        private var _phone: Double!
        private var _url: String!
        private var _zipCode: Double!
        private var _addedToFav: Int!

        var name: String! {
            return _name
        }

        var area: String! {
            return _area
        }

        var latitude: Double! {
            return _latitude
        }

        var longitude: Double! {
            return _longitude
        }

        var followers: Int! {
            return _followers
        }

        var happyHour: String! {
            return _happyHour
        }

        var phone: Double! {
            return _phone
        }

        var url: String! {
            return _url
        }

        var zipCode: Double! {
            return _zipCode
        }

        var addedToFav: Int! {
            return _addedToFav
        }



        init(name: String,area: String! , latitude: Double, longitude: Double, followers: Int, happyHour: String, phone: Double, url: String, zipCode: Double, addedToFav: Int) {
            self._name = name
            self._area = area
            self._latitude = latitude
            self._longitude = longitude
            self._followers = followers
            self._happyHour = happyHour
            self._phone = phone
            self._url = url
            self._zipCode = zipCode
            self._addedToFav = addedToFav
        }

        init(barData: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {


            if let name = barData["name"] as? String {
                 self._name = name
            }

            if let area = barData["area"] as? String {
                self._area = area 
            }

            if let latitude = barData["lattitude"] as? Double {
                self._latitude = latitude
            }

            if let longitude = barData["longitude"] as? Double {
                self._longitude = longitude
            }

            if let followers = barData["followers"] as? Int {
                self._followers = followers
            }

            if let happyHour = barData["happyHour"] as? String {
                self._happyHour = happyHour
            }

            if let phone = barData["phone"] as? Double {
                self._phone = phone
            }

            if let url = barData["url"] as? String {
                self._url = url
            }

            if let zipCode = barData["zipCode"] as? Double {
                self._zipCode = zipCode
            }

            if let addedToFav = barData["addedToFavorites"] as? Int {
                self._addedToFav = addedToFav
            }
        }


    }
```

I created a DataService class with a singleton

Data service class file:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

let URL_BASE = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

class DataService {

    static let ds = DataService()

    private var _REF_BASE = URL_BASE
    private var _REF_BARS = URL_BASE.child("data").child("bars")



    var REF_BASE: FIRDatabaseReference {
        return REF_BASE
    }

    var REF_BARS: FIRDatabaseReference {
        return _REF_BARS
    }
}
```

And my modified viewController file (i did not use a tableViewController)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController ,  UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

    var baruri = [Bar]()



    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        myTableView.dataSource = self
        myTableView.delegate = self


        DataService.ds.REF_BARS.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
                for snap in snapshot {
                    print(snap)
                    if let barData = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                        let bar = Bar(barData: barData)
                        self.baruri.append(bar)
                        print(self.baruri)
                        self.myTableView.reloadData()
                    }
                   self.myTableView.reloadData()
                }
               self.myTableView.reloadData()
            }
            self.myTableView.reloadData()
        }


        )

    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView( _ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return  baruri.count
    }

    func tableView( _ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "newCell", for: indexPath) as! NewCell

        var baruriTabel: Bar!

        baruriTabel = baruri[indexPath.row]

        cell.barNameLBl.text = baruriTabel.name
        cell.followersNrLbl.text = String(baruriTabel.followers)
        cell.areaLbl.text = baruriTabel.area
        cell.addedToFavoritesLbl.text = String(baruriTabel.addedToFav)
        cell.happyHourLbl.text = baruriTabel.happyHour
        cell.urlLbl.text = baruriTabel.url
        cell.lattitudeLbl.text = String(baruriTabel.latitude)
        cell.longitudeLbl.text = String(baruriTabel.longitude)
        cell.phoneLbl.text = String(baruriTabel.phone)
        cell.zipCode.text = String(baruriTabel.zipCode)

        return cell
    }


}
```